# can you please explain the last part of this code?

Tags: python, list, loops

```
CYCLE_INPAIRS = 'I am going to cycle into these sentence letters in pairs'

for i in range(0, len(CYCLE_INPAIRS)-1, 2):  
    print(CYCLE_INPAIRS[i] + CYCLE_INPAIRS[i + 1])
```

the second part of print 
`'CYCLE_INPAIRS[i + 1]'` which i don't understand.

why would he concatenate  `CYCLE_INPAIRS` and add `"1"` to `"i"`?!

thanks

Comment: because he want to cycle it in 'pairs', that's why taking two at a time.

Comment: To do exactly what he mentions, i.e. "cycle the sentence letters in **pairs**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation of the entire code as each line builds off of another.  If you have any questions, just comment.

```
CYCLE_INPAIRS = 'I am going to cycle into these sentence letters in pairs'
```

We are assigning a string here.

```
for i in range(0, len(CYCLE_INPAIRS)-1, 2):
```

This line is very important to understanding the code. Here we are iterating through 0 to the length of our string, `CYCLE_INPAIRS` by **2**'s

```
    print(CYCLE_INPAIRS[i] + CYCLE_INPAIRS[i + 1])
```

Finally, for the last line we are taking the character at the index i and the character directly after that (hence the `+ 1`)

### How to cycle by 3's

The code ends up being very similar.  But I think this will help illustrate the concept:

```
CYCLE_TRIPPLES = 'I am going to cycle into these sentence letters in pairss'
```

CYCLE_TRIPPLES has a number of characters divisible by **3** (I had to add another `s`).

```
for i in range(0, len(CYCLE_TRIPPLES)-1, 3):
```

In this instance, I have changed the amount we jump to **3**'s.

```
    print(CYCLE_TRIPPLES[i] + CYCLE_TRIPPLES[i + 1] + CYCLE_TRIPPLES[i + 2])
```

Next, we are now adding 3 adjacent characters together.  So, I added `CYCLE_TRIPPLES[i + 2]`.

Comment: you mean that  CYCLE_INPAIRS[i] prints the first letter  which is 'I'  &  CYCLE_INPAIRS[i+1] prints the next letter to it, right?  okay, how it can  be done if i want to cycle the string in triples or fours?

Comment: I added an example for how to print it every 3

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of the entire code:

```
CYCLE_INPAIRS = 'I am going to cycle into these sentence letters in pairs'
```

Here You declare a string. you want to take pair of every two character. That means you want take first two character first, then second pair and so on.

```
for i in range(0, len(CYCLE_INPAIRS)-1, 2):
```

above code simply loop to your string by incremental value 2. That means for loop is looping for i=0,2,4,6,8....... in this way.

```
print(CYCLE_INPAIRS[i] + CYCLE_INPAIRS[i + 1])
```

At first loop i=0 that's why CYCLE_INPAIRS[i] + CYCLE_INPAIRS[i + 1] get the value CYCLE_INPAIRS[0] and CYCLE_INPAIRS[1] that means CYCLE_INPAIRS[0] = 'I' and CYCLE_INPAIRS[1] = ' ' and so on....
Here i+1 always contains odd value 1,3,5.........

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's supposed to print 2 letters from the string `CYCLE_INPAIRS`. The for loop runs through every **two** letters, and prints them. The first line would print `I` and a space.